# Can Linq be used to find if value matches part of a larger string?

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have looked into RegEx & SQLMatch with linq but I cant seem to find an applicable rule for my situation. What I am trying to create would be..

```
//dataCollected[0] = { Name="joe", Url="http://my.home.site/" }
//dataCollected[N] = { Name="example", Url="http://german.home.site/" }

public bool hasParent(string test_url){
    var obj = dataCollected.Where(s => ( test_url.contains(s.Url)));
    return obj.Count() > 0;
}

bool  result  = hasParent("http://my.home.site/ShouldBeTrue"); //Finds http://my.home.site/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost there, it should be the other way around. Also, use LINQ `Any`. This will return true if any matches are found:

```
public bool hasParent(string test_url)
{
    return dataCollected.Any(s => test_url.Contains(s.url));
}
```

Comment: It should be `s.Url.Contains(test_url)`

Comment: I think @TheGreatCO got it wrong, you had it right the first time. Currently your code will return false for the example call.

Comment: It should be pointed out that this LINQ will return as soon as the first result is found, so the worst case scenario for this is it must scan ALL the items, as opposed to always scanning all the items each time.

Comment: That would only be true if the Url in dataCollected was the equal or larger string. I need it to find true when  s.url = "http://my.site.home/" & test_url ="http://my.site.home.edu/questions"

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko are you sure? Because test_url is a string, whereas dataCollected is an array of objects.  So the .Contains should be applied to the string member of the object, not the object itself.

Comment: @TheGreatCO `test_url.Contains(s.Url)`

Comment: @Grundy, you are correct, I had it backwards.  I was pointing out in the original post it was `s.Contains(test_url)`, but it should be `test_url.Contains(s.Url)` @gleng forgot the `.Url` part.

Comment: I originally forgot the .Url part. @TheGreatCO pointed that out and I have since fixed!

Comment: This is still wrong. It should be as Grudy pointed out, `test_url.Contains(s.Url)`. They want to test whether the passed in url contains any urls in the array, not the ohter way round.